# I want to make format out its result to a variable instead of printing it

Tags: formatting

I am trying to build a URL from several components, format function seems to do what I want. However, it prints the url instead of assigning it to a variable.

How do I do in Emacs equivalent of (format nil "String") from Common Lisp.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding by the OP.

Answer (score 6):

`#'format` actually returns the formatted value; it doesn't print it out. However, many ways of evaluating code *do* print the returned value -- e.g., `#'eval-last-sexp`.

Here's some code (run in ielm) that saves the result to a variable, then checks that variable:

```
ELISP> (setq myvar (format "some %s here" "text"))
"some text here"
ELISP> myvar
"some text here"
ELISP> (string-equal myvar "some text here")
t
```

Comment: I didn't notice I had princ in front of my format. Looks like I need a break.